# What does $W^{1,p}(I)\subset C\big(\overline{I}\big)$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, sobolev-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded open interval. [Brézis book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis%20sobolev&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=bRnwUpFWh-KwBLHDgugO&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20sobolev&f=false) states that *the injection $W^{1,p}(I)\subset C(\overline{I})$ is compact for all $1<p\leq\infty$*.

Elements of $W^{1,p}(I)$ are functions whose domain is $I$ and elements of $C(\overline{I})$ are functions whose domain is $\overline{I}$. So, I would like an explanation on the meaning of the inclusion $W^{1,p}(I)\subset C(\overline{I})$.

In the begining of the chapter is proved that for each $u\in W^{1,p}(I)$ there exists a $\tilde{u}\in C(\overline{I})$ such that $u=\tilde{u}$ a.e. on $I$. When the author says "the injection $W^{1,p}(I)\subset C(\overline{I})$" is he talking about the application
$u\mapsto\tilde{u}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This inclusion means that every element of $W^{1,p}(I)$ can be *identified* with an element of $C\big(\bar I\big)$.

Let me explain what this *identification* means:

The most subtle issue here is the nature of the elements of $W^{1,p}(I)$. Let's remind that this space is defined to be the *completion* of $C^\infty(I)$ with respect to the $W^{1,p}$ norm.

So, we first take
$X=\{u\in C^\infty(I): \|u\|_{1,p}<\infty\}$, where
$$
\|u\|_{1,p}=\left(\int_0^1 |u(x)|^p+|u'(x)|^p\right)^{1/p},
$$
then observe that this space is not complete, and hence it is not a Banach space. And then define its completion as $W^{1,p}(I)$.

Now, what do the elements of the completion look like? They are not functions yet! They are equivalent classes of equi-convergent Cauchy sequences, i.e., classes of Cauchy sequence, where the difference of two sequences in same the class tends to zero, in the $\|\cdot\|_{1,p}$-norm.

And the critical question:

*Why are we allowed to identify these equivalence classes with elements of $C\big(\bar I\big)$*?

Because, if $\{u_n\}\subset X$ is a $\|\cdot\|_{1,p}$-Cauchy sequence, then it is also a Cauchy sequence with respect to the the supremum norm, as the $\|\cdot\|_{1,p}$-norm is stronger than the supremum norm. And as $\{u_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the supremum norm, it has a  (unique) limit $u\in C\big(\bar I\big)$, since the last space is complete, with respect to the supremum norm. This allows us to identify the equivalence class of the $\|\cdot\|_{1,p}-$Cauchy sequence $\{u_n\}$ with this $u\in C\big(\bar I\big)$, and enables us to think of $W^{1,p}(I)$ as a subset of $C\big(\bar I\big)$.

Furthermore, this limit $u\in C\big(\bar I\big)$ is independent of the choice of the Cauchy sequence $\{u_n\}$. To see this, if $\{v_n\}$ is another Cauchy sequence in the same equivalence class, then
$$
u_1,v_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n,v_n,\ldots,
$$
is also a Cauchy sequence of the same equivalence class, and hence converging, in the supremum norm, to the same limit.

Comment: That's a nice answer. (+1)